# Inaccurate calculation of distance with distHaversine

Tags: r, spatial

Hello:) I am a master's student tracking birds, and am in need of some help. This is my second SO post, so I apologize if my format isn't correct.

I am trying to sort out a bug with calculating the distance between two geographical coordinates.

Below is a subset of my dataset.

```
df <- structure(list(runID = c(518372151L, 536672894L, 536672896L, 
536672898L, 518383421L, 536672931L, 520458858L, 518397128L, 518398891L, 
520458859L, 500661721L, 519816711L, 496919104L, 519816729L, 496919111L, 
519816732L, 500661722L, 500615767L, 537068880L, 528315198L, 496920823L, 
505690395L, 536915137L, 536841259L, 506384869L, 536916210L, 554114218L, 
536847451L, 510391414L, 508441427L, NA, 518373803L, 536672895L, 
536670669L, 520458872L, 509356336L, 496919133L, 496919265L, 500615762L, 
509648199L, 509356637L), batchID = c(10389869L, 10935418L, 10935418L, 
10935418L, 10389869L, 10935418L, 10409949L, 10389870L, 10389870L, 
10409949L, 9900171L, 10405108L, 9809042L, 10405108L, 9809042L, 
10405108L, 9900171L, 9896069L, 10961382L, 10682281L, 9809043L, 
9983872L, 10938055L, 10936570L, 10016701L, 10938151L, 11242599L, 
10937045L, 10183601L, 10135657L, 10389869L, 10389869L, 10935418L, 
10935014L, 10409949L, 10155800L, 9809043L, 9809043L, 9896069L, 
10159733L, 10155800L), ts = c(1674787173.3748, 1674834169.0175, 
1675019190.4739, 1675081685.0159, 1675131831.1043, 1675486150.0107, 
1675619763.4157, 1675624113.3303, 1675687120.4277, 1675687157.5273, 
1676241622.1676, 1676401821.1076, 1676490425.806, 1676490701.0246, 
1676550608.0756, 1676564719.6008, 1676638113.5264, 1679236511.8943, 
1679314080.063, 1680176218.5757, 1680181350.1342, 1680266657.1351, 
1680347875.5379, 1680348625.4723, 1680621954.0557, 1680785940.21, 
1680787390.0877, 1680790389.8307, 1681178571.3142, 1681178758.6583, 
NA, 1674833579.6502, 1674862089.2623, 1675690930.3138, 1675702129.5877, 
1675889037.7959, 1676985903.1585, 1677079332.3759, 1677166124.7042, 
1678199920.3978, 1678364818.3011), sig = c(-57.2487, -70.7311, 
-72.2136, -65.0611, -56.3906, -69.2483, -68.3716, -55.113, -52.0845, 
-69.6601, -64.9641, -70.6522, -69.1682, -73.2088, -68.1927, -71.7475, 
-68.3707, -63.6102, -71.3087, -67.6047, -69.6245, -73.7175, -66.8755, 
-72.0029, -69.4483, -69.182, -71.8858, -68.6348, -72.3921, -72.3131, 
NA, -57.1334, -68.635, -70.3466, -69.0429, -73.3014, -67.4207, 
-71.2844, -68.9192, -62.4557, -66.3137), motusTagID = c(72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 
72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L, 72305L
), mfgID = c(121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L, 123L
), tagDeployID = c(44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 44554L, 
44554L, 44554L, 44554L), deployDay = c("2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00"), time = structure(c(1674787173.3748, 1674834169.0175, 
1675019190.4739, 1675081685.0159, 1675131831.1043, 1675486150.0107, 
1675619763.4157, 1675624113.3303, 1675687120.4277, 1675687157.5273, 
1676241622.1676, 1676401821.1076, 1676490425.806, 1676490701.0246, 
1676550608.0756, 1676564719.6008, 1676638113.5264, 1679236511.8943, 
1679314080.063, 1680176218.5757, 1680181350.1342, 1680266657.1351, 
1680347875.5379, 1680348625.4723, 1680621954.0557, 1680785940.21, 
1680787390.0877, 1680790389.8307, 1681178571.3142, 1681178758.6583, 
1674773400, 1674833579.6502, 1674862089.2623, 1675690930.3138, 
1675702129.5877, 1675889037.7959, 1676985903.1585, 1677079332.3759, 
1677166124.7042, 1678199920.3978, 1678364818.3011), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Latitude = c(42.6154, 42.6354, 42.6354, 
42.6354, 42.6154, 42.6354, 42.5829, 42.6154, 42.6154, 42.5829, 
43.4538, 43.6659, 43.9597, 43.6659, 43.9597, 43.6659, 43.4538, 
43.2497, 43.8041, 43.9474, 43.9597, 43.9597, 43.9474, 44.0461, 
44.5049, 44.2852, 44.2082, 44.5434, 44.9993, 45.05, 42.621167, 
42.6154, 42.6354, 42.7259, 42.5829, 42.9254, 43.9597, 43.9597, 
43.2497, 42.6, 42.9254), Longitude = c(-80.4582, -80.5577, -80.5577, 
-80.5577, -80.4582, -80.5577, -80.3984, -80.4582, -80.4582, -80.3984, 
-81.1985, -80.7268, -80.7847, -80.7268, -80.7847, -80.7268, -81.1985, 
-81.8249, -81.7103, -80.464, -80.7847, -80.7847, -80.464, -80.0943, 
-80.9472, -81.1, -80.6122, -79.9797, -79.9835, -80.0322, -80.4600769, 
-80.4582, -80.5577, -80.5623, -80.3984, -81.3673, -80.7847, -80.7847, 
-81.8249, -81.4533, -81.3673), recvDeployID = c(8251L, 2429L, 
2429L, 2429L, 8251L, 2429L, 7756L, 8251L, 8251L, 7756L, 7228L, 
645L, 8594L, 645L, 8594L, 645L, 7228L, 9146L, 5727L, 8590L, 8594L, 
8594L, 9543L, 9497L, 8247L, 9403L, 9541L, 8229L, 7934L, 7905L, 
NA, 8251L, 2429L, 9368L, 7756L, 8193L, 8594L, 8594L, 9146L, 8538L, 
8193L), recvDeployName = c("Birds Canada HQ", "Walsingham Super Tower", 
"Walsingham Super Tower", "Walsingham Super Tower", "Birds Canada HQ", 
"Walsingham Super Tower", "Old Cut", "Birds Canada HQ", "Birds Canada HQ", 
"Old Cut", "Mitchell", "Conestogo", "Mount Forest", "Conestogo", 
"Mount Forest", "Conestogo", "Mitchell", "Pinery_Provincial_Park", 
"Point Farms Provincial Park", "Luther_Marsh", "Mount Forest", 
"Mount Forest", "Luther_Marsh", "Monocliffs", "Sydenham", "Chesley", 
"Priceville", "Wasaga", "Split Rock", "GB-Alexander", "", "Birds Canada HQ", 
"Walsingham Super Tower", "Langton", "Old Cut", "Auzins", "Mount Forest", 
"Mount Forest", "Pinery_Provincial_Park", "Hentz", "Auzins"), 
    month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
    date = structure(c(19384, 19384, 19386, 19387, 19388, 19392, 
    19393, 19393, 19394, 19394, 19400, 19402, 19403, 19403, 19404, 
    19404, 19405, 19435, 19436, 19446, 19446, 19447, 19448, 19448, 
    19451, 19453, 19453, 19453, 19458, 19458, 19383, 19384, 19384, 
    19394, 19394, 19396, 19409, 19410, 19411, 19423, 19425), class = "Date"), 
    season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Migration", 
    "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", 
    "Migration", "Migration", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter"), distance = c(234.471489168055, 11082.3727147704, 
    0, 0, 11082.3727147704, 11082.3727147704, 17759.5276305268, 
    6684.03291028197, 0, 6684.03291028197, 90403.3323951357, 
    52640.1276482721, 8315.45900731159, 8315.45900731159, 8315.45900731159, 
    8315.45900731159, 52640.1276482721, 69811.021198638, 15518.8279409308, 
    138759.386585177, 35700.857323963, 0, 35700.857323963, 41196.5932227749, 
    95315.505220496, 17432.3701175875, 54318.7176093354, 70689.6511934138, 
    8838.8969578562, 5508.99779581073, NA, 234.471489168055, 
    11082.3727147704, 1729.87889701448, 18434.2184498018, 108026.043745825, 
    67266.588851771, 0, 116407.196045145, 42681.5471131637, 10996.4210553791
    ), bearing = c(333.010726969135, 178.101478244716, NA, NA, 
    358.101478244716, 178.101478244716, 356.879467836294, 174.836195397183, 
    NA, 354.836195397183, 170.132209228821, 4.03919726314535, 
    140.814965248019, 320.814965248019, 140.814965248019, 320.814965248019, 
    184.039197263145, 182.752272590097, 34.7100317886633, 1.01890837436861, 
    179.642052092727, NA, 359.642052092727, 2.58071760777744, 
    174.940664527545, 192.644132890398, 358.563380769542, 5.10287224383563, 
    92.7431160558265, 169.760584201358, NA, 333.010726969135, 
    178.101478244716, 107.218393996858, 351.789300215105, 176.797079466799, 
    15.3920853438558, NA, 185.884441468829, 345.738176801435, 
    29.47177915118), cardinal = c("NW", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", 
    "N", "S", NA, "N", "S", "N", "SE", "NW", "SE", "NW", "S", 
    "S", "NE", "N", "S", NA, "N", "N", "S", "S", "N", "N", "E", 
    "S", NA, "NW", "S", "E", "N", "S", "N", NA, "S", "N", "NE"
    ), Treatment = c("Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement"), ReleaseLat = c(42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117), ReleaseLon = c(-80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008), DistFromRelease = c(234.804133976308, 
    10870.1473986602, 10870.1473986602, 10870.1473986602, 234.804133976308, 
    10870.1473986602, 6902.62489451353, 234.804133976308, 234.804133976308, 
    6902.62489451353, 83515.2348317087, 35253.0338067467, 43532.8676352541, 
    35253.0338067467, 43532.8676352541, 35253.0338067467, 83515.2348317087, 
    152310.314644161, 140654.670953719, 24466.6699111863, 43532.8676352541, 
    43532.8676352541, 24466.6699111863, 48737.3075630705, 63930.074918398, 
    77164.060469389, 33622.509744572, 64652.5379416452, 69531.1378842598, 
    66072.950761229, 0.349500870811351, 234.804133976308, 10870.1473986602, 
    11540.2447008501, 6902.62489451353, 101132.43751287, 43532.8676352541, 
    43532.8676352541, 152310.314644161, 110565.363282303, 101132.43751287
    )), row.names = 233:273, class = "data.frame")
> dput(df.2023FULLuseable[233:262,])
structure(list(runID = c(518372151L, 536672894L, 536672896L, 
536672898L, 518383421L, 536672931L, 520458858L, 518397128L, 518398891L, 
520458859L, 500661721L, 519816711L, 496919104L, 519816729L, 496919111L, 
519816732L, 500661722L, 500615767L, 537068880L, 528315198L, 496920823L, 
505690395L, 536915137L, 536841259L, 506384869L, 536916210L, 554114218L, 
536847451L, 510391414L, 508441427L), batchID = c(10389869L, 10935418L, 
10935418L, 10935418L, 10389869L, 10935418L, 10409949L, 10389870L, 
10389870L, 10409949L, 9900171L, 10405108L, 9809042L, 10405108L, 
9809042L, 10405108L, 9900171L, 9896069L, 10961382L, 10682281L, 
9809043L, 9983872L, 10938055L, 10936570L, 10016701L, 10938151L, 
11242599L, 10937045L, 10183601L, 10135657L), ts = c(1674787173.3748, 
1674834169.0175, 1675019190.4739, 1675081685.0159, 1675131831.1043, 
1675486150.0107, 1675619763.4157, 1675624113.3303, 1675687120.4277, 
1675687157.5273, 1676241622.1676, 1676401821.1076, 1676490425.806, 
1676490701.0246, 1676550608.0756, 1676564719.6008, 1676638113.5264, 
1679236511.8943, 1679314080.063, 1680176218.5757, 1680181350.1342, 
1680266657.1351, 1680347875.5379, 1680348625.4723, 1680621954.0557, 
1680785940.21, 1680787390.0877, 1680790389.8307, 1681178571.3142, 
1681178758.6583), sig = c(-57.2487, -70.7311, -72.2136, -65.0611, 
-56.3906, -69.2483, -68.3716, -55.113, -52.0845, -69.6601, -64.9641, 
-70.6522, -69.1682, -73.2088, -68.1927, -71.7475, -68.3707, -63.6102, 
-71.3087, -67.6047, -69.6245, -73.7175, -66.8755, -72.0029, -69.4483, 
-69.182, -71.8858, -68.6348, -72.3921, -72.3131), motusTagID = c(72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 
72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L, 72303L), mfgID = c(121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L), tagDeployID = c(44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 
44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L, 44552L), deployDay = c("2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00", 
"2023-01-26 22:50:00", "2023-01-26 22:50:00"), time = structure(c(1674787173.3748, 
1674834169.0175, 1675019190.4739, 1675081685.0159, 1675131831.1043, 
1675486150.0107, 1675619763.4157, 1675624113.3303, 1675687120.4277, 
1675687157.5273, 1676241622.1676, 1676401821.1076, 1676490425.806, 
1676490701.0246, 1676550608.0756, 1676564719.6008, 1676638113.5264, 
1679236511.8943, 1679314080.063, 1680176218.5757, 1680181350.1342, 
1680266657.1351, 1680347875.5379, 1680348625.4723, 1680621954.0557, 
1680785940.21, 1680787390.0877, 1680790389.8307, 1681178571.3142, 
1681178758.6583), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Latitude = c(42.6154, 42.6354, 42.6354, 42.6354, 42.6154, 
    42.6354, 42.5829, 42.6154, 42.6154, 42.5829, 43.4538, 43.6659, 
    43.9597, 43.6659, 43.9597, 43.6659, 43.4538, 43.2497, 43.8041, 
    43.9474, 43.9597, 43.9597, 43.9474, 44.0461, 44.5049, 44.2852, 
    44.2082, 44.5434, 44.9993, 45.05), Longitude = c(-80.4582, 
    -80.5577, -80.5577, -80.5577, -80.4582, -80.5577, -80.3984, 
    -80.4582, -80.4582, -80.3984, -81.1985, -80.7268, -80.7847, 
    -80.7268, -80.7847, -80.7268, -81.1985, -81.8249, -81.7103, 
    -80.464, -80.7847, -80.7847, -80.464, -80.0943, -80.9472, 
    -81.1, -80.6122, -79.9797, -79.9835, -80.0322), recvDeployID = c(8251L, 
    2429L, 2429L, 2429L, 8251L, 2429L, 7756L, 8251L, 8251L, 7756L, 
    7228L, 645L, 8594L, 645L, 8594L, 645L, 7228L, 9146L, 5727L, 
    8590L, 8594L, 8594L, 9543L, 9497L, 8247L, 9403L, 9541L, 8229L, 
    7934L, 7905L), recvDeployName = c("Birds Canada HQ", "Walsingham Super Tower", 
    "Walsingham Super Tower", "Walsingham Super Tower", "Birds Canada HQ", 
    "Walsingham Super Tower", "Old Cut", "Birds Canada HQ", "Birds Canada HQ", 
    "Old Cut", "Mitchell", "Conestogo", "Mount Forest", "Conestogo", 
    "Mount Forest", "Conestogo", "Mitchell", "Pinery_Provincial_Park", 
    "Point Farms Provincial Park", "Luther_Marsh", "Mount Forest", 
    "Mount Forest", "Luther_Marsh", "Monocliffs", "Sydenham", 
    "Chesley", "Priceville", "Wasaga", "Split Rock", "GB-Alexander"
    ), month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), date = structure(c(19384, 19384, 19386, 
    19387, 19388, 19392, 19393, 19393, 19394, 19394, 19400, 19402, 
    19403, 19403, 19404, 19404, 19405, 19435, 19436, 19446, 19446, 
    19447, 19448, 19448, 19451, 19453, 19453, 19453, 19458, 19458
    ), class = "Date"), season = c("Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", 
    "Winter", "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", 
    "Migration", "Migration", "Migration", "Migration"), distance = c(234.471489168055, 
    11082.3727147704, 0, 0, 11082.3727147704, 11082.3727147704, 
    17759.5276305268, 6684.03291028197, 0, 6684.03291028197, 
    90403.3323951357, 52640.1276482721, 8315.45900731159, 8315.45900731159, 
    8315.45900731159, 8315.45900731159, 52640.1276482721, 69811.021198638, 
    15518.8279409308, 138759.386585177, 35700.857323963, 0, 35700.857323963, 
    41196.5932227749, 95315.505220496, 17432.3701175875, 54318.7176093354, 
    70689.6511934138, 8838.8969578562, 5508.99779581073), bearing = c(333.010726969135, 
    178.101478244716, NA, NA, 358.101478244716, 178.101478244716, 
    356.879467836294, 174.836195397183, NA, 354.836195397183, 
    170.132209228821, 4.03919726314535, 140.814965248019, 320.814965248019, 
    140.814965248019, 320.814965248019, 184.039197263145, 182.752272590097, 
    34.7100317886633, 1.01890837436861, 179.642052092727, NA, 
    359.642052092727, 2.58071760777744, 174.940664527545, 192.644132890398, 
    358.563380769542, 5.10287224383563, 92.7431160558265, 169.760584201358
    ), cardinal = c("NW", "S", NA, NA, "N", "S", "N", "S", NA, 
    "N", "S", "N", "SE", "NW", "SE", "NW", "S", "S", "NE", "N", 
    "S", NA, "N", "N", "S", "S", "N", "N", "E", "S"), Treatment = c("Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement", "Fergus Short Displacement", 
    "Fergus Short Displacement"), ReleaseLat = c(42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 
    42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117, 42.62117), ReleaseLon = c(-80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, 
    -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008, -80.46008), DistFromRelease = c(234.804133976308, 
    10870.1473986602, 10870.1473986602, 10870.1473986602, 234.804133976308, 
    10870.1473986602, 6902.62489451353, 234.804133976308, 234.804133976308, 
    6902.62489451353, 83515.2348317087, 35253.0338067467, 43532.8676352541, 
    35253.0338067467, 43532.8676352541, 35253.0338067467, 83515.2348317087, 
    152310.314644161, 140654.670953719, 24466.6699111863, 43532.8676352541, 
    43532.8676352541, 24466.6699111863, 48737.3075630705, 63930.074918398, 
    77164.060469389, 33622.509744572, 64652.5379416452, 69531.1378842598, 
    66072.950761229)), row.names = 233:262, class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to populate the DistFromRelease with the distance between Latitude and Longitude, from ReleaseLat and Release Lon. I've checked that all my coordinates are correct. The problem is that the distances being calculated are not correct. I don't need it to be crazy accurate, hence using distHaversine over other options. However, some of the distances that should be a lot bigger, and it is causing issues with my analysis.

Here is the code I am using to calculate the distance between the points:

```
df <- df |> 
  mutate(DistFromRelease = distHaversine(df.2023FULLuseable[,10:11], df.2023FULLuseable[,21:22]))
```

It *appears* to be working, and I think it is working sometimes.
Below is a map and a plot for the individual with motusTagID = 72303, the individual for which I discovered the mistake in my code. The map shows the path the bird I tracked, the red circle pointing to a distance that pretty much checks out with GoogleEarth, but the red square should be a lot bigger of a distance than is being calculated (see the plot image).

I hope this makes sense. It must be a small mistake that I can't see... I appreciate any help!

Comment: `geosphere::distHaversine()` ? Coordinate column order in your datasets seems to be Latitude, Longitude while for `distHaversine` it should be longitude, latitude.

Comment: Is this a common enough typo that it's worth answering, or should this be closed as "due to a typo" ?